# 'CORBA::LongDoubleSeq' has not been declared

Tags: c++, idl, omniorb

I built omniORB-4.2.1 by VS2013+Cygwin(0.9.1-1) on Windows7 32bit.

I placed omniORB under C drive.

Then I tried to build SALOME-KERNEL by MinGW and got following error message related to omniORB.

```
[5%] Building CXX object idl/CMakeFiles/SalomeIDLKernel.dir/SALOME_ExceptionSK
.cc.obj
In file included from C:/omniORB-4.2.1/include/omniORB4/CORBA.h:221:0,
                 from c:/src/salome7/buildKernel/idl/SALOME_Exception.hh:6,
                 from c:/src/salome7/buildKernel/idl/SALOME_ExceptionSK.cc:3:
C:/omniORB-4.2.1/include/omniORB4/dynAny.h:151:47: error: 'CORBA::LongDoubleSeq'
 has not been declared
     virtual void insert_longdouble_seq(CORBA::LongDoubleSeq& value) = 0;
                                               ^
C:/omniORB-4.2.1/include/omniORB4/dynAny.h:171:20: error: 'LongDoubleSeq' in nam
espace 'CORBA' does not name a type
     virtual CORBA::LongDoubleSeq* get_longdouble_seq() = 0;
                    ^
idl/CMakeFiles/SalomeIDLKernel.dir/build.make:333: recipe for target `idl/CMakeF
iles/SalomeIDLKernel.dir/SALOME_ExceptionSK.cc.obj' failed
make[2]: *** [idl/CMakeFiles/SalomeIDLKernel.dir/SALOME_ExceptionSK.cc.obj] Erro
r 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:86: recipe for target `idl/CMakeFiles/SalomeIDLKernel.dir/a
ll' failed
make[1]: *** [idl/CMakeFiles/SalomeIDLKernel.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:127: recipe for target `all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Does anyone know how to this problem?

SALOME? omniORB? Which is the matter?